# Unable to connect to a docker container microservice

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, windows-container

I am running a microservice inside a docker container using docker compose.
The docker-compose.yml file is as follows.

```
version: '2.1'
services:
flousermanagement:
  build: 
    context: ../FloUserManagement/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "5001:5001"
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - 

      ../FloUserManagement/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/data: 
      c:\floUserManagement\data
```

The dockerfile.

```
 FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-preview2-sdk-nanoserver
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FloUserManagement.dll"]
 ARG source=.
 WORKDIR /floUserManagement
 ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5001
 EXPOSE 5001
 EXPOSE 8080
 COPY $source .
```

I am unable to connect to locahost. The code running without the container works just fine but not within the container. I tried tracking the requests on the container but I am not able to hit any endpoints inside the container on locahost:5000.

Is it due to the dotnet core 2.0.0-preview2 version upgrade? 
Is it due to localhost not getting mapped in IPv6 from IPv4?
What could be the workaround for this?

I am running docker enterprise edition on azure vm.
Windows Server 2016 datacenter
Intel Xeon 2.4GHz Dual Core. x64 bit 7GB RAM. I am using Docker enterprise and not the community edition.

Comment: why is this tagged with azure? has nothing to do with azure, since it doesnt work on localhost

Comment: Your app is in 5001. Why do you say 5000?

Comment: Sorry for that. It's a typo mistake. It's actually localhost:5001

Comment: I am running the docker container on Azure VM. That's why I tagged the question in azure.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in current implementation of WinNAT. Connection to localhost published port is not going to work from the **same**  host. You will be able to use mapped port from outside container but not locally. This is not seems to be scheduled to be fixed untill next major release of Windows 2016. (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#limitations-of-windows-containers-for-localhost-and-published-ports)

Comment: Hey Greg, I just checked the docs. But I am not able to access the service using container ip and port as well from host browser. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Publish your image on github

Comment: I don't know how to publish my docker image on github. Please share a set of instructions to do so.